# Archive file after MFT transfer

Tags: websphere-mq-fte

We're using IBM MQFT for a file transfer between 2 systems and we have a requirement to move the original file to a different location on the source file system once the transfer is complete.

From the knowledge center MFT documentation what I can see is that we may need to write a user exit program to do this. I guess I would set the *source_file_disposition* to "leave" and use the exit program to move the file.

Is that the correct way to go about it, or there a simpler way to do this that I'm not seeing?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few options for you.

1. You can run a command or a shell script or an Ant script as part of postSrc parameter of [fteCreateTransfer](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=commands-ftecreatetransfer-start-new-file-transfer) command. Once transfer is complete MFT will run the specified command to move the files from source to another directory.
2. As you mentioned a Java exit can be written to move the files after transfer completion.

You may want to refer samples Java exit and Ant Script [here](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mft).